# powering a circuit with USB micro; what to do with unused pins

Tags: power, usb

I want to power an old board (mostly TTL ICs) with [this](http://www.tme.eu/sk/Document/4e78b9a2ed279d3cbd52e22a72ea9364/MUSB-K152-30.pdf) through-hole USB micro AB connector. I will have to *create* the pads for the pins with a scalpel, so the **main question** is: can I just connect the DATA and ID pins to the ground, or **must** I leave them unconnected (e.g. cut them their own little pad)?

A side question: I plan to use a dedicated charger; But would grounding the pins (if allowed) prevent powering this board via a PC USB port? Board needs about 300mA.

Comment: Duplicate? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209911/will-cutting-the-data-lines-of-usb-still-let-the-power-to-go-through

Comment: You should use data pins to identify the charger before taking more than 100mA from it, theoretically. Or you just use a dumb charger that provides whatever you need without asking questions.

Comment: Bradman175's link to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209911/will-cutting-the-data-lines-of-usb-still-let-the-power-to-go-through is indeed useful reading, but that is a question about charging a USB device that might have some assumptions about the USB protocol and (in)formal charging extensions to it; this is a question about powering a custom device that would have no awareness of USB.

Answer (score -1):

I've done this before but with a micro USB cable and cables shoved against Vcc and GND, except I also had some eeproms on the board. It worked for a while until I accidentally flashed the more sensitive eeprom. I didn't bother with the other output pins of the USB cable. I also had it plugged into my laptop and as I said it worked fine, the only tricky part was that the connections weren't all that secure.

So yeah, you don't need to connect the other pins for it to work as a 5V, 0.5A power source, if a traditional USB out or wall adapter (5V, more if USB3.0 out or a faster charger).