# Turning off USB devices by disconnecting 5V line?

Tags: usb

I would like to have a physical privacy switch for the USB 2.0 webcam and headset that's connected to my desktop computer (I'm too lazy to reach behind the computer and unplug the USB, also the tangle of wires needed to make this work easily annoys my inner perfectionist).

I was thinking about making a nice looking box with a illuminated lever switch that passes through D+, D- and GND of two USB ports and interrupts the V+.

Is this a reasonable way to ensure USB peripherials are really off?
I'm mostly concerned about possible damage to the host computer or the peripherials, when the data pins are connected and power is not.
Will the devices enumerate correctly when powered on again this way?
Also I wouldn't be too happy if for example it turned out that the device can somehow suck power through the data lines.

Would it be better to switch all four lines of the USB?

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209809/will-cutting-only-the-power-lines-damage-the-data-lines-or-the-device , but that question has two conflicting answers :)

Comment: Just put a small bag over the camera.

Answer (score 2):

When a bus-powered USB device has power removed, it cannot communicate on the bus in any way.

Bus-powered equipment without internal batteries, like a webcam, will therefore do nothing if the bus power is removed.

USB hubs with power switches are available cheaply and commercially and will disable any bus-powered device without internal batteries.